# What is the best way to communicate among multiple processes in ubuntu

Tags: process, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I've three different machine learning models in python. To improve performance, I run them on different terminals in parallel. They are communicating and sharing data with one another through files. These models are creating batches of files to make available for other. All the processes are running in parallel but dependent on data prepared by other process. Once a process A prepares a batch of data, it creates a file to give signal to other process that data is ready, then process B starts processing it, while looking for other batch too simultaneously. How can this huge data be shared with next process without creating files? Is there any better way to communicate among these processes without creating/deleting temporary files in python?
Thanks

Comment: "*One process waits until a specific file is created in a directory and then starts its job*" is **not a `[PARALLEL]`-processing** but a plain, pure-**`[SERIAL]` workflow** (As you've confirmed in your own words,that one-*job-**starts***-only-after-another-job-***was*-finished**-only-after-another-job-***was*-finished** ) Any amount of terminals,run concurrently,does not mean anything about the process-workflow of jobs,that run(or wait in a pure-`[SERIAL]` fashion in a sequence,as you confirmed)an actual flow of work. Pipelines via ZeroMQ/nanomsg are smart lightweight data-passing (no sharing)

Comment: @user3666197 All the processes are running in parallel but dependent on data prepared by other process. Once a process A prepares a batch of data, it creates a file to give signal to other process that data is ready, then process B starts processing it, while looking for other batch too simultaneously.

Comment: Yes,it's **exactly the nature of a pure-`[SERIAL]` processing** -it waits,till some previous(predecessor)process has completed data a next process is dependent on.In true-`[PARALLEL]` processing,there is no such serialisation into a sequence of one-after-another-after-another. Symphonic orchestra performs "together" in a true-`[PARALLEL]` fashion,not violins 1st,after violins finish, drums start,after drums finish,the piano starts,after the piano finish organs,after organs came in flutes,after flutes oboes start,after oboes there comes a trombone...that's **not a `[PARALLEL]` orchestration**

Comment: No, this wait is only for first time. Process A takes more time then process B and process C takes more time than both. So Once a batch is prepared by A, B quickly processes it to make available for C. As C takes more time than A&B, next batch is available to C before it finishes the first.

Comment: Still not a `[PARALLEL]` flow of work. Some level of a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`, with dependencies blocking an independent flow - the sequence of dependencies is introduced by (b)locking until results from a "previous" phase were delivered and made available to the "next" phase processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider running up a small **Redis** instance... a very fast, in-memory data structure server.

It allows you to share strings, lists, queues, hashes, atomic integers, sets, ordered sets between processes very simply.

As it is networked, you can share all these data structures not only within a single machine, but across multiple machines.

As it has bindings for C/C++, Python, bash, Ruby, Perl and so on, it also means you can use the shell, for example, to quickly inject commands/data into your app to change its behaviour, or get debugging insight by looking at how variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do multiprocessing in Python3. Instead of storing results in a file the results are stored in a dictionary (see output)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def multi_processor(function_name):

    file_list = []

    # Test, put 6 strings in the list so your_function should run six times
    # with 6 processors in parallel, (assuming your CPU has enough cores)
    file_list.append("test1")
    file_list.append("test2")
    file_list.append("test3")
    file_list.append("test4")
    file_list.append("test5")
    file_list.append("test6")

    # Use max number of system processors - 1
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count()-1)
    pool.daemon = True

    results = {}
    # for every item in the file_list, start a new process
    for aud_file in file_list:
        results[aud_file] = pool.apply_async(your_function, args=("arg1", "arg2"))

    # Wait for all processes to finish before proceeding
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Results and any errors are returned
    return {your_function: result.get() for your_function, result in results.items()}


def your_function(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        print("put your stuff in this function")
        your_results = ""
        return your_results
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    some_results = multi_processor("your_function")
    print(some_results)
```

The output is

```
put your stuff in this function
put your stuff in this function
put your stuff in this function
put your stuff in this function
put your stuff in this function
put your stuff in this function
{'test1': '', 'test2': '', 'test3': '', 'test4': '', 'test5': '', 'test6': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sqlite database to share files.

I made this for this exact purpose:

https://pypi.org/project/keyvalue-sqlite/

You can use it like this:

```
from keyvalue_sqlite import KeyValueSqlite

DB_PATH = '/path/to/db.sqlite'

db = KeyValueSqlite(DB_PATH, 'table-name')
# Now use standard dictionary operators
db.set_default('0', '1')
actual_value = db.get('0')
assert '1' == actual_value
db.set_default('0', '2')
assert '1' == db.get('0')
```